# WebService works with Jetty but not with Tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, tomcat6, jetty-8

I am banging my head against a wall at the moment. I did some development to create a WebService using CXF and Spring. It all worked fine with Jetty 8, but when I try and run it with Tomcat 6 I can't even get the WSDL from the request. Below are the details:

**My webservice interface:**

```
@WebService(name="AlertService")
public interface AlertWebService {

    @WebMethod
    HandleAlertResponse openHandleAlert(@WebParam(name = "request") HandleAlertRequest request) throws ServiceException;
}
```

**My webservice impl:**

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "c.h.g.p.service.ws.alert.AlertWebService", serviceName = "AlertService")
public class AlertWebServiceImpl implements AlertWebService {

    @Override
    public HandleAlertResponse openHandleAlert(HandleAlertRequest request) throws ServiceException {
        //Do some stuff
    }
```

**My web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app ...>   
  <display-name>Prime Service Webapp</display-name>

  <listener>
    <listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/prime-service-webapp/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**Endpoint definition**

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

<bean id="alertWebService" class="c.h.g.p.service.ws.alert.AlertWebServiceImpl" />

<jaxws:endpoint implementor="#alertWebService" address="/AlertService" />
```

**URL that I hit which gives me 404 error**

```
http://localhost:8090/prime-service-webapp/AlertService?wsdl
```

I have changed my tomcat config to look at port 8090. I just drop my war called prime-service-webapp into webapps directory of tomcat. Adding an index.html file into the prime-service-webapp directory also seems to resolve ok. But I can't get the wsdl at all.

Any ideas - let me know. Is there anything in specific to tomcat 6 server config I need to change to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit i know nothing about jetty, but in tomcat, the way you put it, you need to use this URL:

```
http://localhost:8090/prime-service-webapp/prime-service-webapp/AlertService?wsdl
```

Have a try with that.  The reason is tomcat assigns the war name as context root by default, and you have instructed your cxf servlet to listen to

```
<url-pattern>/prime-service-webapp/*</url-pattern>
```

which means another level under context root (even if it is the same)

Comment: Great - thats it! But how can I tell tomcat that I actually want to use just one "prime-service-webapp" in the url? Without modifying the web.xml which works fine with Jetty. I need compatability with both app servers.

Comment: I have never tried in tomcat :S According to this documentation, you may have to do some mangling on the server's configuration files after deploying (or in its admin console)  http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html